# Postgres: meaning of `timestamp without time zone at time zone`

Tags: sql, postgresql, timezone

I am having some trouble understanding how to deal in Postgres with time zone semantic:
Consider this table

```
TABLE MyTable (
    MyDate                            TIMESTAMP                NOT NULL,
    // other columns
);
```

And this query

```
SELECT  *
FROM MyTable
WHERE // conditions
AND tstzrange(#{start} ::timestamp with time zone, #{end} ::timestamp with time zone] @> MyDate::timestamp without time zone at time zone 'CET'
```

I understand that `Postgres` only stores the `epoch` value i.e. no time zone info is ever stored, so I understand the need to specify timezone for `start` and `end` as they are formatted strings that Postgres needs to calculate the `epoch` for.

What I don't really understand is:
`MyDate::timestamp without time zone at time zone 'CET'`

Postgres knows the `epoch` for `MyDate` since it's their values are stored, why the need to "convert" to a time zone ?
What are we actually saying here and can this be simplified ?

Answer (score -1):

Postgres never stores timezone information in `timestamp` or `timestamptz`.  In the `timestamptz` case the timestamp being stored is rotated to a `UTC` value using either the timezone information in the presented timestamp or the value of the setting `TimeZone` and then stored. In the `timestamp` case that is not done. On output a `timestamptz` is rotated back from `UTC` to whatever the `TimeZone` setting is or what via `at time zone <some_tz>`. In the `timestamp` case the retrieved value is assumed to be the setting of `TimeZone` unless you override with `at time zone <some_tz>`. Best practices is that you use `timestamptz`.